# Get row index to update another dataframe in loop

Tags: r

I have the following data:

EDIT:

```
 df<- data.frame(
  id = c(432, 324, 322, 331, 242,443,223 ), 
  
  desc1= c("metal","steels&iron","irons\\copper", "sports material", "leather material", "durable goods", "electronic store")
  ,
  store_names = c("ik bros","steel idrs", "kb materials",  "ca pty (ltd)",  "bkk stores", "k/k \\shop", "h/j & jj")
  ,
  class = c("", "unknown","",  "sports", "unknown", "unknown", "") 
)
```

I want to search keywords from both desc1 and desc2 and assign a string value to class column. For example, keywords can be

```
indus_1 <- c("iron", "steel")
goods_store_1 <- c("goods", "store", "stores")
electr_1 <- c("electronic", "chips", "semiconductor")
unlabelled_1 <- c("leather")
```

here variable names indus_1, sports_1 and so on will be used to assign a string value to class. For instance, if "metal" keyword is found I assign indus after stripping away "_1" to class. In my approach, I am finding index of rows where keywords found and copying them to the copy of same dataframe, but this take quite long for a larger dataset, and may miss few classes as I am using `\\b` to find exact match. Here is the expected output:

```
  id            desc1  store_names       class
  432            metal      ik bros            
  324      steels&iron   steel idrs       indus
  322    irons\\copper kb materials       indus     
  331  sports material ca pty (ltd)      sports
  242 leather material   bkk stores  unlabelled
  443    durable goods   k/k \\shop goods_store
  223 electronic store     h/j & jj      electr
```

I am looking for a more efficient method to do the same, a fully dplyr version would be preferable. Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: @MrFlick please see the updated question. `df2` is the copy of same dataframe.

Comment: Would every row have only one occurrence of keyword ? Or it can have "metal" and "sports" in the same row ? What would be output in this case?

Comment: and also electronics and goods in the same row. Will that be goods store or electronics? And how do you decide?

Comment: @Onyambu, I prefer to generalize the class as much as possible, so if electronic goods is a goods store, that is okay.  However, in case electr class have other terms like electrical equipment, electronic chips, semi-conductor devices, I want all such classes to end up in electr class.

Comment: @RonakShah, yes it certainly can multiple keywords in each row. It is unlikely metal and sports occur together, metal keyword should have related category, such as steel. So, `indus_1 <- c("iron", "steel", "irons", "steelsindust", "iron&steel" )` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case, you could do:

```
vars_1 <- mget(ls(pattern = '_1'))
vars_1 <- vars_1[!grepl('vars', names(vars_1))]
pat <- sub("_1", "", names(vars_1))
names(pat) <- sprintf(".*(%s).*", unlist(vars_1))

df %>%
  mutate(class = str_replace_all(invoke(str_c, across(starts_with('desc'))), pat))

  id            desc1        desc2       class
1 432   iron and metal      ik bros       indus
2 324  sports material ca pty (ltd)      sports
3 322 leather material   bkk stores  unlabelled
4 331    durable goods   k/k \\shop goods_store
5 242 electronic goods     h/j & jj      electr
```

Comment: how to create pat variable when any class for example indus_1 have more than one keywords?

Comment: @Vendetta collapse them together with the `|` operator using `paste` etc

Comment: I tried ‘names(pat) <- paste0( sprintf(“.*(%s).*”, unlist(vars_2) ), collapse=“|”)’, but this does not help.

Comment: @Vendetta You will have to ask a different question altogether. The solution given here works for the case asked here. I am not able to edit since i DO NOT KNOW HOW your data looks exactly. Please consider closing this question by accepting any of the given solutions then ask a new question with the new iformation

Comment: @Vendetta also it should be: `names(pat)<- sapply(vars_2, function(x) paste0(sprintf(".*(%s).*", x), collapse = "|"))`

Answer (score 1):

Logically my answer is similar to @Onyambu 's answer but with few tweaks.

```
library(tidyverse)

mget(ls(pattern = '_1')) %>%
  stack() %>%
  group_by(ind = sub('_1', '', ind)) %>%
  summarise(values = sprintf('.*\\b(%s)\\b.*', paste0(values, collapse = '|'))) %>%
  select(2, 1) %>%
  deframe() -> pat

pat
#.*\\b(electronic|chips|semiconductor)\\b.*   .*\\b(goods|store|stores)\\b.*
#                                  "electr"           "goods_store" 
#                   .*\\b(iron|steel)\\b.*         .*\\b(leather)\\b.*
#                                   "indus"             "unlabelled"
df %>%
  mutate(class2 = str_replace_all(desc1, pat), 
         class2 = ifelse(desc1 == class2, '', class2))

#   id            desc1  store_names   class      class2
#1 432            metal      ik bros                    
#2 324      steels&iron   steel idrs unknown       indus
#3 322    irons\\copper kb materials                    
#4 331  sports material ca pty (ltd)  sports            
#5 242 leather material   bkk stores unknown  unlabelled
#6 443    durable goods   k/k \\shop unknown goods_store
#7 223 electronic store     h/j & jj              electr
```

For `id = 322` it doesn't match `indus` because we are looking for an exact match. `indus_1` has `iron` whereas `desc1` column has `irons`.

Comment: the pattern creation part is great, in the second part of the code where you apply str_replace_all why desc1 entries are being copied to class2? Instead of using str_replace_all, can we instead use search based function such as str_detect/grepl to first find the string and then replace it in an ifelse?